# Right Divison of a Vector in MatLab

Tags: matlab, vector, linear-algebra, division

Given a and b vectors:

```
a=[1;0;0];
b=[0;1;0];
```

What is the meaning of:

```
C=a/b
```

I understand "/" (Matrix Right Division) should be equivalent to

```
C=a*inv(b)
```

But of course, a vector doesn't have a "nicely" defined inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant part of the documentation for [`mrdivide`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html) is the third bullet point. Given a system of linear equations `x*A = b`, then:

> If `A` is a rectangular `m`-by-`n` matrix with `m ~= n`, and `B` is a matrix with `n` columns, then `x = B/A` returns a least-squares solution of the system of equations `x*A = B`.

In your example, you get the following:

```
>> a=[1;0;0];
>> b=[0;1;0];
>> C=a/b

C =

     0     1     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
```

And you can confirm that this is a solution for the system of equations `C*b = a`:

```
>> C*b

ans =

     1
     0
     0
```

Comment: google had sent me [here](https://es.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/mrdivide.html), thanks for pointing the right way

Comment: Ah, yeah. Overloaded operator for a different toolbox. Ironically, I ran aground of that link first too.